# I want to run a python file in a subdirectory

Tags: python

I want to run a file in a subdirectory. The file is importing custom modules.

I get the following error.
How can I call it normally?

**Directory structure**

```
planet/
    __init__.py
    db/
        __init__.py
        mysqldb_handler.py
    scheduler/
        __init__.py
        collect_candidate.py
```

**run python**

```
planet/scheduler> python3 collect_candidate.py
```

**Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "planet/scheduler/collect_candidate.py", line 1, in <module>
    from planet.db.mysqldb_handler import MysqlDBHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'planet'
```

Comment: try `from ..db.mysqldb_handler import MysqlDBHandler`

Comment: Why is your script buried in the package it wants to import?

Answer (score 0):

Adding parent directory to *Path* is pretty good way if you need to import modules like that frequently.

For similar example structure:

```
some_folder
 ┃
 ┣━ __init__.py
 ┃
 ┣━ main_script
 ┃   ┣━ __init__.py
 ┃   ┃
 ┃   ┗━ actual_main_script.py
 ┃
 ┖━ module
     ┣━ __init__.py
     ┃
     ┗━ some_module.py
```

Code of `actual_main_script.py`:

```py
from sys import path
from os.path import abspath
path.append(abspath(".."))

from module import some_module
```

And this way results are consistent with either direct or indirect calls on source code.

```
# X:\main_script
> py .\actual_main_script.py

# X:\
> py .\main_script\actual_main_script.py

# Absolute path
> py X:\main_script\actual_main_script.py
```